# Undefined variable: records in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\display_prsc.php on line 29

Tags: php, html, mysql, apache, html-table

I want to retrieve data from MySql table. I am using Xampp, phpMyAdmin etc... I followed this tutorial step by step: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IHdd02IK2Jg

But I get this error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: records in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\display_prsc.php on line 29

And a warning:

> Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\display_prsc.php on line 29

It just displays the column names when i run it.

```
    <? php

       //make connection
       mysql_connect('localhost','root','');

       //select_db
       mysql_select_db('mynewdb');

       $sql="SELECT * FROM new";

       $records=mysql_query($sql);
    ?>

    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Program Scores Table</title>

    <body>

     <table width="600" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
     <tr>
             <th>Year</th>
             <th>Criteria</th>
             <th>Score</th>
     <tr>

    <?php

       while ($new=mysql_fetch_assoc($records)){

             echo"<tr>";
             echo"<td>".$new['py']."</td>";
             echo"<td>".$new['pcrit']."</td>";
             echo"<td>".$new['psco']."</td>";
             echo"</tr>";
       }
     ?>

      </table>
      </body>
      </head>
      </html>
```

Comment: If in your tutorial the guy uses `mysql_*` I would highly recommend you to stop with this tutorial! And read this: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: There are many errors in this little piece of code, very terribly written.

Comment: Your html is a complete mess!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note the space in your first php tag. 
You have `<? php` , it should be `<?php`

And since it seems you are starting  to learn, avoid learning things deprecated. Don't use MySQL, use PDO or Mysqli.

Comment: Hi can't see the video which he is following, i'm just try to help him the way I can :)

Comment: OP, if you switch to an IDE (e.g. NetBeans) you'll spot this tag error immediately, since it changes code colouring.

Answer (score 4):

You have a few errors in your code:

1. Wrong php opening tag

You have to remove the space in your php opening tag, e.g.

```
<?php
```

2. Weird html

Almost your entire html is wrong! I would recommend you to read a book or watch a basic html tutorial

So your entire code should look something like this:

```
<?php

    //make connection
    mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');

    //select_db
    mysql_select_db('mynewdb');

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM new";

    $records = mysql_query($sql);

?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Program Scores Table</title>
    </head> <!-- head tag closed here -->

    <body>

        <table width="600" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
            <tr>
                <th>Year</th>
                <th>Criteria</th>
                <th>Score</th>
            </tr> <!-- forgot / to close the tag -->

            <?php
            while ($new = mysql_fetch_assoc($records)){
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $new['py'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $new['pcrit'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $new['psco'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            ?>

      </table>

    </body>   
</html>
```

**Side Notes:**

1. What can be improved?

- I would do some basic error checking e.g. if the connection failed and so on
- Use [`mysqli_*`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) with prepared statements, or [`PDO`](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements) with prepared statements, they are much safer! (We live in 2015)
- (Also if the guy in your tutorial uses `mysql_*`, change the tutorial!)

So that you don't only have your old code working, here your improved code:

```
<?php

        //Database stuff
        $hostname = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $dbname = "mynewdb";

        try {

            $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
            $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


            $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM new");
            $stmt->execute();


            //Close Connection
            $dbh = null;

        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Program Scores Table</title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <table width="600" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
            <tr>
                <th>Year</th>
                <th>Criteria</th>
                <th>Score</th>
            </tr> 

            <?php
            while ($new = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $new['py'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $new['pcrit'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $new['psco'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            ?>

      </table>

    </body>   
</html>
```

2. Coding side notes

Add [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>
```

Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
<?php

       //make connection
      $con= mysql_connect('localhost','root','');

       //select_db
      $select= mysql_select_db('mynewdb',$con);

       $sql="SELECT * FROM new";

       $records=mysql_query($sql);
    ?>

    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Program Scores Table</title>

    <body>

     <table width="600" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
     <tr>
             <th>Year</th>
             <th>Criteria</th>
             <th>Score</th>
     <tr>

    <?php

       while ($new=mysql_fetch_array($records)){

             echo"<tr>";
             echo"<td>".$new['py']."</td>";
             echo"<td>".$new['pcrit']."</td>";
             echo"<td>".$new['psco']."</td>";
             echo"</tr>";
       }
     ?>

      </table>
      </body>
      </head>
      </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you using Prepared statements for MySQL instead of clean MySQL, it's not secure at all, and will give you problems later on.

A lille guide here.
http://www.w3schools.com/pHp/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple errors in your code. But for the error, it is due to `mysql_query()` returns **FALSE** at line:

```
$records=mysql_query($sql);
```

Then, the line `while ($new=mysql_fetch_assoc($records)){` cannot get the value of `$records`, thus produce the errors.

---

Other errors are:

HTML

- missing DOCTYPE
- missing meta charset
- a missing `</tr>`
- a misplaced `</head>`
- be modern, use CSS to style your HTML instead of using HTML tag attributes

PHP

- didn't check the return value of functions before using them
- use of deprecated `mysql_*` functions; use PDO / MySQLi instead
- extra space at `<? php`

Comment: *missing </head>* no :D look at the end of OP's html. Pretty bad html. Also look at the first table row from OP...